# Requirement to build a 'branded' site

Tags: asp.net

If I may I will explain how the powers that be where I am working have told me this will work.  It sounds feasable and i'm getting a head start on it so I don't shoot myself in the foot later.

It's a generic reporting web site that will have it's look and feel changed, really it will simply be different images and a title but I want it to be as flexible as possible.

One site will be created which I'm going to start on shortly.

This will be registered in IIS as one site and under about 10 other sites a Virtual Directory will be created pointing at this one site, this allows the 10 sites out there to connect to the generic reporting site. Depending on the source site the branding will change.

So for clarification I create a site called LongLegs.com

Then under 3 of our sites we create VD's so we have

www.GillianAnderson.com/LongLegs - so the site features pic of Scully!
babe.jolie.com/LongLegs - Site will be the same but feature pics of Jolie instead.
mailserver.company.co.uk/LongLegs - site will feature pics of the amazing mail server we got here.

So based on the URL somehow I want to brand the site but remember i'm creating a solution which is simply LongLegs.

The site itself will force a login and this will determine data they have access to.  Only the site look is changed dependant on the 'source' site.

Ideas please i'm really not sure how to solve that part.  I can quite happily use the ASP NET membership for the accounts and the schema for the DB is all set, even the webservice exposed waiting to collect the latest data from each of our long legged lovelies and they will only see there own. But for now the site i'm concocting only has generic legs and this must change!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the site look, use themes in your site, look up the url (either `Request.ServerVariables` or `Request.Url`) and [switch themes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx35bd89.aspx) based on that.

Against the user the options I can see are:

- store which site (theme) they are against as a user property and switch when logged in. Of course, that would fall down if they are allowed to be in multiple sites.
- store allowed sites against the user and have an extra step when validating the login to see if the current path is ok for that user.
- perhaps set each site to have its own applicationid in asp.net membership and let that take care of it. This would fall down if you are only having one set of source code on the page server as that needs to be set in the web.config iirc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I believe Themes bound to the users profile and hidden from the user is going to be enough.  Thanks very much.